# How to pass ArrayList using Intent?

Tags: android

I want to pass model ArrayList using Intent. My case is like I am in Activity and wants to pass Arraylist from Activity to Fragment. How can achieve this?

Comment: So use `Bundle` and `putSerializable`. How can you reach `Intent` in `Fragment` from `Activity`?

Comment: pass using put extra and get using get extra with help of bundle object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this code in Activity:**

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key",mainList);
YourFragment chatFragment=new YourFragment ();
chatFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Add this code in Fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            ArrayList<Object> list=(ArrayList<Object>)bundle.get("key");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am given as demo instead of ArrayList<Object> use ArrayList of your own Model Class which is Seralizable

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Object>T getObjectFromJson(String responseBody, Class<T> classType) {
        new Gson().fromJson(responseBody, classType);
    }

    public String getJsonString(Object object) {
        new Gson().toJson(object).toString();
    }
```

Add a dependency for gson in your build.gradle and then use teh function getJsonString() to convert your arraylist into string and pass it in the intent and in the other activity use the function getObjectFromJson() to convert the string back to the arraylist object

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Gson

**to send in intent**

```
intent.putExtra("myList", Gson().toJson(mylist))
```

**to retrive**

```
val mylist = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<Object>>(listJson, object : TypeToken<HashMap<Object>>() {}.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard way to pass arraylist between two activities. Use Parcelable. Refer this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html for more details.